# How to express in Kotlin "assign value exactly once on the first call"?

Tags: kotlin, design-patterns, delegates, lazy-evaluation

Looking for a natural Kotlin way to let `startTime` be initialized only in a particular place and exactly once.

The following naive implementation have two problems:

1. it is not thread safe
2. it does not express the fact "the variable was or will be assigned exactly once in the lifetime of an Item instance"

---

```
class Item {
    var startTime: Instant?

    fun start(){
        if (startTime == null){
            startTime = Instant.now()
        }

        // do stuff
    }
}
```

I believe some kind of a delegate could be applicable here. In other words this code needs something similar to a `lazy` variable, but without initialization on first read, instead it happens only after explicit call of "touching" method. Maybe the `Wrap` calls could give an idea of possible implementation.

```
class Wrap<T>(
  supp: () -> T
){
   private var value: T? = null
   private val lock = ReentrantLock()
  
   fun get(){
     return value
   }

   fun touch(){
      lock.lock()

      try{
          if (value == null){
              value = supp()
          } else {
              throw IllegalStateExecption("Duplicate init")
          }
      } finally{
        lock.unlock()
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: I don't understand why `lazy()` does not fit your case. What if your "touching" method just invoke read on a lazy value to initialize it? What is your expected behavior when someone try to read the value before the "touching" method got invoked?

Comment: @broot Value has an initial state (i.e. `null`) and reader gets it when reading the value before "touching"

Comment: I completely rewrote my answer to satisfy the requirement to only set the value from the `start()` method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about combining [`AtomicReference.compareAndSet`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/16/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/atomic/AtomicReference.html#compareAndSet(V,V)) with a custom [backing field](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/properties.html#backing-fields)?

You can use a private setter and make sure that the only place the class sets the value is from the `start()` method.

```
class Item(val value: Int) {
    private val _startTime = AtomicReference(Instant.EPOCH)
    var startTime: Instant?
        get() = _startTime.get().takeIf { it != Instant.EPOCH }
        private set(value) = check(_startTime.compareAndSet(Instant.EPOCH, value)) { "Duplicate set" }

    fun start() {
        startTime = Instant.now()
    }

    override fun toString() = "$value: $startTime"
}

fun main() = runBlocking {
    val item1 = Item(1)
    val item2 = Item(2)
    println(Instant.now())
    launch { println(item1); item1.start(); println(item1) }
    launch { println(item1) }
    delay(1000)
    println(item2)
    item2.start()
    println(item2)
    println(item2)
    item2.start()
}
```

Example output:

```
2021-07-14T08:20:27.546821Z
1: null
1: 2021-07-14T08:20:27.607365Z
1: 2021-07-14T08:20:27.607365Z
2: null
2: 2021-07-14T08:20:28.584114Z
2: 2021-07-14T08:20:28.584114Z
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalStateException: Duplicate set
```

Comment: Wow! Expressive and impressive code. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I think your `Wrap` class is a good starting point to implement this. I would definitely make it a property delegate and `touch()` could be much simplified:

```
fun touch() {
    synchronized(this) {
        check(value == null) { "Duplicate init" }
        value = supp()
    }
}
```

Then you can remove `lock`. But generally, this is a good approach.

If you would like to reuse `lazy` util from stdlib then you can do this by wrapping it with another object which does not read its value until asked:

```
class ManualLazy<T : Any>(private val lazy: Lazy<T>) {
    operator fun getValue(thisRef: Any?, property: KProperty<*>): T? {
        return if (lazy.isInitialized()) lazy.value else null
    }

    fun touch() {
        lazy.value
    }
}

class Item {
    private val _startTime = ManualLazy(lazy { Instant.now() })
    val startTime: Instant? by _startTime

    fun start(){
        _startTime.touch()
    }
}
```

Of course, depending on your needs you can implement it in a much different way, using a similar technique.

This may be considered exploiting or hacking lazy util. I agree and I think `Wrap` approach is a better one.

Comment: I like your idea. To implement a solution I'm going to combine your answer with Adam's answer to decouple Item from those get/set routines.